# New Perspective on Paul?

Tags: protestantism, paul-apostle, npp

What is the *New Perspective on Paul*?

It's promoted by numerous New Testament scholars such as N.T Wright, James D. G. Dunn and E.P Sanders. I have read a lot of their articles and books on it. I find it really intriguing, and it has shaped my theology. It does kind of challenge the traditional Protestant interpretation of Pauline theology. Although, the scholars I mentioned above themselves are Protestants. What does the New Perspective say that is different?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! Thanks for your question. However, it may get downvotes or be put on hold because it is primarily asking for personal opinions, whereas this site is more about the views of denominations or groups of Christians, such as Catholic or Lutheran views on a subject. If you edited your question to ask for the views of particular groups, it would fit better here. For some tips on questions that work here, please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The New Perspective says that what Paul is saying in his Epistles, is not as simple as post reformation scholars say that it is. The new perspective would be better apply named, the new Protestant perspective.  I would love to answer this question directed to Catholics, however, Lee is correct, this is difficult to address as asked.

Comment: The new perspective on Paul can actually be found in Origen's commentary on Romans, oddly enough; making the New Perspective actually about 1800 years old

Comment: @shiningcartoonist Can you provide a link to that commentary.  It is not easily found.